# How to crawl several review pages using Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, web-crawler

I have a question about web-crawler.
I want to get several review pages using Python.

Here my code for web-crawler.

```
URL = 'https://www.example.co.kr/users/sign_in'

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain', 'User-Agent':user_agent}
login_data = {'user':{'email':'id', 'password':'password', 'remember_me':'true'}}

client = requests.session()
login_response = client.post(URL, json = login_data, headers = headers)
print(login_response.content.decode('utf-8'))

jre = 'https://www.example.co.kr/companies/reviews/ent?page=1'
index = client.get(jre)
html = index.content.decode('utf-8')
print(html)
```

This code only gets page=1, but I want to get page=1, page=2, page3 .... using format method. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a while o a for loop on each page, depending on your necessities.
Try a pattern like this:

```
page = 1
while page <= MAX_PAGE or not REACHED_STOPPING_CONDITION:

  # Compose page url
  jre = f'https://www.example.co.kr/companies/reviews/ent?page={page}'
  # Get page url
  index = client.get(jre)

  # Do stuff...

  # Increment page counter
  page += 1
```

I think that once you had access to website you do not have any necessity to perform login again. If it is needed, you should insert login part into the loop.

Another way to navigate website pages is to find a sort of "Next page" or "Previous page" reference in the document and then interact with them:

```
# Compose page url
jre = 'https://www.example.co.kr/companies/reviews/ent?page=1'
# Get page
index = client.get(jre)

while page <= MAX_PAGE or not REACHED_STOPPING_CONDITION:

  # Do stuff...

  # Search next page element (ex. by CSS selector)
  jre.find_element_by_css_selector('next-page').click()
  # Increment page counter
  page += 1
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't show anything. I'm using on jupyter notebook and how can i get html information in code.

Comment: You can inspect the page using your browser. Alternatively you can inspect DOM properties with dedicated libraries such as BeautifulSoup

Comment: When i using your recommedation code, output is "\njre = 'https://www.example.co.kr/companies/reviews?page=1'\nindex = client.get(jre)\n\nhtml = index.content.decode('utf-8')\nprint(html)\n"